# Web.py on shared hosting

Tags: python, performance, web.py

I just built a small app with the very cool and minimalistic `web.py`.

I am using a cheap shared hosting package (at WebFaction) and have installed web.py via virtualenv. I cannot use the system python since I need additional packages which I'm not allowed to install into the system python.

So now I start my app with

```
/home/me/mypython/python myapp.py <myport>
```

It feels like a cumbersome solution, and I'm not sure how much traffic this setup can take. Any general hints?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't seem like it would be able to take any more or less traffic if it were using the system python. If the command line is cumbersome...perhaps create an alias? Not really sure what your concerns are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you're not using fastcgi? That's probably considerably better than trying to use some high-numbered port, particularly since your webhost may not be very happy about that at all. There are a few notes on doing that (on dreamhost, but it should be similar for you) in this post:

http://thefire.us/archives/261

Comment: I don't know much about fastcgi, that's why I'm not using it. :) Thanks for the hint, I'll have a look at it. Btw, WebFaction offers the possibility to install an arbitrary app and gives you a port to run it on, so that's not a problem.

Comment: In general, fastcgi or wsgi are going to be your best bet as far as serving python web apps go. That way your "real" webserver, be it lighttpd or apache, can do most of the heavy lifting related to serving http while your python app handles the logic behind things.